# How to call an html form back

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have this html form which will then it will call addstuds.php to execute the code for inserting records in mysql database.

```
    <form name="formcheck" method="post" action="addstuds.php">
<td width="30" height="35"><font size="3">*I D Number:</td>
<td width="30"><input  name="idnum" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" maxlength="5" id='numbers'/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="30" height="35"><font size="3">*Year:</td>
<td width="30"><input  name="yr" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" maxlength="5" id='numbers'/></td>

<td width="30" height="35"><font size="3">Section:</td>
<td width="30"><input  name="sec"  type="text" maxlength="15"></td>
</tr>
```

What do I need to do so that the regstuds.php(html form) will be the one that will be seen again after the insert code in addstuds.php will finish executing?Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include the form handling code you have in addstuds.php at the top of regstuds.php and have the form action take you back to regstuds.php by using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].

As for the success message, you could set a flag if the add is successful and echo the script tag if that flag is true.

Answer (score 1):

You can `include` or `require` the file after execution.

Or, you can just do a good 'ol HTTP redirect: `header( 'Location: regstuds.php' );`.
Only problem with doing a redirect is that if you already sent any headers back to the client, you cannot modify them after they have been already sent. But of course, there's a solution to that too: use JavaScript: `window.location = "regstuds.php";` will do it.

Comment: thanks, this is okay but I cant see the confirmation that I put in addstuds.php anymore:
echo "<script>alert('Record successfully added!')</script>";